# Exactly minutes between two times

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Need a formula that gives me the minutes between two dates. This should be used in asp classic

eg: between 08:00-20:00 I want to distribute times by 16 times.
(I have 16 pieces of candy that I have to eat at exact intervals between 08:00 and 20:00)

What will be the mathematical formula for that calculation?
(720 min between start and end time)
I will eat a piece of candy at 08:00 and at 20:00
What will be the exact 16 minute run when I get to eat a piece of candy?

I have tried, but can't solve it, any ideas?

Comment: See [`DateDiff`](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_datediff.asp). Then divide by the number of candies -1. So in your case 720/15 = 48 minutes.

Comment: As described in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/xhtyw595(v=vs.84)) use the `DateDiff()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit odd that you're looking to calculate the minutes, yet in the answer you posted, you skip this calculation and instead set the answer as a predetermined variable value.

As mentioned multiple times, `DateDiff` is what you need to calculate the minute intervals, along with `DateAdd` to calculate the 16 different times.

```
Dim StartDate, EndDate, DistributionCount, Interval, x

StartDate = Cdate("2023-03-27 08:00:00")
EndDate = Cdate("2023-03-27 20:00:00")
DistributionCount = 16

Interval = Round(DateDiff("n",StartDate,EndDate)/DistributionCount)

For x = 1 To DistributionCount
        
    Response.Write x & " - " & DateAdd("n",Interval*x,StartDate) & "<br>"
    
Next
```

Output:

> 1 - 3/27/2023 8:45:00 AM
> 2 - 3/27/2023 9:30:00 AM
> 3 - 3/27/2023 10:15:00 AM
> 4 - 3/27/2023 11:00:00 AM
> 5 - 3/27/2023 11:45:00 AM
> 6 - 3/27/2023 12:30:00 PM
> 7 - 3/27/2023 1:15:00 PM
> 8 - 3/27/2023 2:00:00 PM
> 9 - 3/27/2023 2:45:00 PM
> 10 - 3/27/2023 3:30:00 PM
> 11 - 3/27/2023 4:15:00 PM
> 12 - 3/27/2023 5:00:00 PM
> 13 - 3/27/2023 5:45:00 PM
> 14 - 3/27/2023 6:30:00 PM
> 15 - 3/27/2023 7:15:00 PM
> 16 - 3/27/2023 8:00:00 PM

Comment: Congratulations, you’ve done their homework for them.

Answer (score -1):

The formula you want is time in minutes divided by the pieces of candy minus one.
minutesBetweenBites = totalMinutes/(piecesOfCandy -1)

We're subtracting one because you're taking your first piece of candy at zero minutes and there are only 15 pieces to take in the remaining 720 minutes.

Comment: Yes, that's a good start.
minutesBetweenBites = totalMinutes/(piecesOfCandy -1)
48 min between each piece of candy.
What I need is to find out which minutes it will be automatically.
ex: 08:00, 08:48, and so on ..

Comment: Create a DateTime variable and set the time part to 08:00
Store your 48 minutes in a variable. 
Print your Time (08:00)
Then For(n==1; n<=16; n++)
{
DateAdd('n', minutesBetweenBites, timeVariable);
print time;
}

Comment: This is a one liner in VBScript - [`DateDiff()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/xhtyw595(v=vs.84)).

Answer (score -2):

This code working fine.
Thank you all for help!

```
piecesOfCandy=16
totalMinutes=720

minutesBetweenBites = totalMinutes/(piecesOfCandy -1)

firstdate ="2023-03-02 08:00:00"
For i = 0 To piecesOfCandy-1
    too=minutesBetweenBites*i
  response.write("The time is " & DateAdd("n",too,firstdate) & "<br />")
Next
```

Comment: This is seriously inefficient use [`DateDiff()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/xhtyw595(v=vs.84)) as already suggested.